# VHDL 2008 > Passing formal generic packages to a hierarquically lower package instantiation

Tags: package, vhdl, generic-list, synthesis

The following two packages and the entity are correctly compiled and simulated, so that `d'19` is assigned to signal `test`.

```
package genpkg is
  generic ( test: natural:=2 );
end package;
```

---

```
library mylib;
use mylib.genpkg;

package genotherpkg is
  generic ( package lgpkg is new mylib.genpkg generic map (<>);
            toadd: natural:=4 );
  constant myconst: natural range 0 to 63:=lgpkg.test+toadd;
end package;
```

---

```
library mylib;
use mylib.genpkg;
use mylib.genotherpkg;

entity ent is
end ent;

architecture arch of ent is
   package mygpkg is new mylib.genpkg generic map (3);
   package myogpkg is new mylib.genotherpkg generic map (mygpkg, 16);
   signal test: integer;
begin
   test <= myogpkg.myconst;
end arch;
```

However, when I try to use an intermediate package:

```
library mylib;
use mylib.genpkg;
use mylib.genotherpkg;

package gentoppkg is
  generic ( package lpkg is new mylib.genpkg generic map (<>) );

  --package mylpkg is new mylib.genpkg generic map (lpkg.test);
  --package lopkg is new mylib.genotherpkg generic map ( mylpkg, 16 );
  package lopkg is new mylib.genotherpkg generic map ( lpkg, 16 );
end package;
```

---

```
library mylib;
use mylib.genpkg;
use mylib.gentoppkg;

entity otherent is
end otherent;

architecture arch of otherent is
   package mygpkg is new mylib.genpkg generic map (3);
   package mytgpkg is new mylib.gentoppkg generic map (mygpkg);
   signal test: integer;
begin
   test <= mytgpkg.lopkg.myconst; 
end arch;
```

The simulator crashes, unless I replace the instantiation of `lopkg` in `gentoppkg` with the commented lines. Yet, that requires mapping each of the generics in `lpkg` to the new instance `mylpkg`. Am I doing something wrong? Or should I take it up with the vendor of the tools?

Comment: Might be worth mentioning which simulator/version.

Comment: It's Questa 10.4c. However, what I'd like to know is whether the formal generic package `lpkg` in `gentoppkg` is considered an instantiation. If not, having to instantiate it makes sense to me. I've tried reading the LRM, but I couldn't find out if it is a limitation of the language.